# ViewPager [FragmentPagerAdapter] inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentmanager

i'm trying to put `ViewPager` into `ListView`

here the code of `ListView AdapterClass`:

```
public class AdapterPager extends BaseAdapter {

.....

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.component_pager, parent, false);
        new ViewHolder(view, itemData.get(position));
    }

 return view;
}
```

View Holder:

```
private class ViewHolder {
  ViewPager pager;
  PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

 public ViewHolder(View view, ModelItem  model){
        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setId(model.getId());  /// uniq ID
        pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
```

then, Pager Adapter:

```
    static final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;

    private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return FragmentComponentPager.newInstance(position, mModel);
        }

        @Override
        public float getPageWidth(int position) {
            float f_width = 1f;
            return f_width;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

    }
```

and, the last, `Pager Fragment`:

```
  public class FragmentComponentPager extends Fragment {
    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";
    static final String ARGUMENT_NAME        = "arg_name";
    int pageNumber;

    public static FragmentComponentPager newInstance(int page, ModelItem data) {
        FragmentComponentPager pageFragment = new FragmentComponentPager();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        if (data != null){
           arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_NAME, data.getName());
        }
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_list, null);          
        TextView tvTitle          = (TextView)     view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setText(getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_NAME));
       return view;
    }
  }
```

when i run it `ListView` shows all items that i've added, but all of them, **except the last one**, with empty `ViewPager`.

and, if i removed `pager.setId(model.getId());` the **first** item shows view pager, and the others empty.

guess that smth wrong with FragmentManager, but have no idea how deal with it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ViewHolder you need to call getChildFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: thank you, for fast answer! could you please clarify have can i got access to getChildFragmentManager? i need to create fragment First and put it to layout?

Comment: You would get it from the Fragment that is displaying the list. Hard to say from the code snippets you have here. You may have to pass it to your list adapter to pass to the ViewHolder.